# How do you color points in a scatterplot by factors in one of the data's columns?

Tags: r, scatter-plot, conditional-formatting

I am working through *R Projects for dummies* and one page has a scatterplot matrix using the iris dataset from UCI. The matrix has the points colored differently based on the species of the iris. The code that the book gives is:

```
iris.uci <- read.csv(url("http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data"),
                     header=FALSE, col.names =c("sepal.length", "sepal.width", "petal.length", "petal.width","species")  )

iris.uci[35,4] = 0.2
iris.uci[38,2:3]= c(3.6, 1.4)

iris.uci$species <- mapvalues(iris.uci$species, from = c("Iris-setosa", "Iris-versicolor", "Iris-virginica"), to = c("setosa", "versicolor", "verginica"))

pairs(iris.uci[,1:4], lower.panel=NULL, cex=2, pch=21, cex.labels =2, 
      bg = c("black", "grey", "white")[iris.uci$species])
par(xpd=NA)
legend("bottomleft", inset=c(-.5,0), legend=c("setosa", "versicolor", "verginica"), pch=21, pt.bg=c("black", "grey", "white"),
       pt.cex =2, y.intersp=1, cex=1.5, bty="n" )
```

For the matrix, this only plots white circles, though the legend code does plot the correct colors. What am I missing?

Comment: Please be sure to include relevant non-base packages; I suspect you're using `plyr::mapvalues`. Is there something specific to *that* `iris` that we cannot use the `data("iris")` built in to R?

Comment: Is there a specific format to include packages? I did not notice any when I asked the question, and I'm sorry if that my question unclear! Thanks for the help!!

Comment: If you read the text for the [tag:r] tag, it gives the suggestion directly to list non-base packages. Format? At a minimum, mention them, though usually it's by including `library(.)` calls in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read `?pairs`, it gives as an example a `pairs(.)` plot as well. In that example, it uses

```r
     pairs(iris[1:4], main = "Anderson's Iris Data -- 3 species",
           pch = 21, bg = c("red", "green3", "blue")[unclass(iris$Species)])
```

which seems fairly similar to yours. You might try to add `unclass(.)` to your own data, but it doesn't work. Why? Because with the default base R `iris` (there seems no need to download your UCI version, btw), "species" is a `factor`, so internally it is stored as an integer and strings referenced based on that.

```r
str(iris)
# 'data.frame': 150 obs. of  5 variables:
#  $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
#  $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
#  $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
#  $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
#  $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...

str(iris.uci)
# 'data.frame': 150 obs. of  5 variables:
#  $ sepal.length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
#  $ sepal.width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
#  $ petal.length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
#  $ petal.width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
#  $ species     : chr  "setosa" "setosa" "setosa" "setosa" ...
```

***However*** ... a few R versions ago, `read.csv` changed its default behavior from `stringsAsFactors=TRUE` (which had been in place for decades?) to `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`, so you get simple strings. If you look at what you're trying to pass to `bg=`, you'll see it is uninteresting:

```r
head( c("black", "grey", "white")[iris.uci$species] )
# [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA
table( c("black", "grey", "white")[iris.uci$species], useNA = "always" )
# <NA> 
#  150
```

That's because you are indexing your index of three colors based on strings, and since your vectors are not named, it finds nothing and returns `NA` for everything.

There are two ways to work around this:

1. Name your colors:

   ```r
   pairs(iris.uci[,1:4], lower.panel=NULL, cex=2, pch=21,
         bg = c(setosa="black", versicolor="grey", verginica="white")[iris.uci$species])
   ```

   [image]

   This has the advantage of you tightly controlling which color goes with each species.
2. `factor` and then `unclass`:

   ```r
   pairs(iris.uci[,1:4], lower.panel=NULL, cex=2, pch=21,\
         bg = c("black", "grey", "white")[unclass(factor(iris.uci$species))])
   ```

   [image]

   (Notice that the order of species I assigned in option 1 are different than shown here; that was intentional, to highlight that doing it this way actually reduces some functionality. There are ways to use `factors` and still control the color, but I find option 1's explicit color assignment to be clearer.)

(FYI, in the original `iris` dataset and in the `iris.uci` download, it's spelled `virginica`.)